# calculate future value daily and deposit addition fund every 30 days in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to use Excel to find future value daily and also add extra deposit every 30 days.

for example. my money started from $100 with 7% annual interest, and if the number of days to grow is 65 days. For every 30days I would add 100 to the money.

There is a website ([Link is here](https://financialmentor.com/calculator/compound-interest-calculator)) that does exactly what I am looking for but I would like to do the calculation. please advice.

Comment: From your public profile, we can see you haven't taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) yet. I suggest you do so then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54040349/edit) to let us know what you've tried so far and how it fails to meet expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=ROUNDUP(SUM(IF(MOD(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,H5)),30)=0,H3,0)*(1+H4/365)^(($H$5+1)-ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,H5))),$H$2*(1+$H$4/365)^(H5+1)),2)
```

This is an array formula and requires the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of the usual Enter.

But this only calculates daily based on a 365 day year and 30 day month cycle.

[image]

Comment: how about if I want to add the deposit at the beginning rather than at the 30, For example start adding deposit at 1 31 61 91 and so on.  Thank you